# Do the Sunni muslims believe in the re-appearance of AL-MAHDI or TAYYIB at the Day of Judgement?

Tags: sunni, shiism, shia-sunni, imam-mahdi, shia-imam

The Twelvers (Jafari school of thought within Shia sect) believe that Imam Al-Mahdi will re-appear at the day of Judgement, while a small faction (known as the Mustali's) within Shia's Ismaili (also known as the Seveners) community believe that Tayyib will re-appear at the day of Judgement, where both Imam Al-Mahdi and Tayyib are in what these respective communities call as occultation (i.e. not visible to the sight but exists).

Since the Sunnis believe in the appearance of a prominent Islamic figure at the day of Judgement before the Isa re-appears (as based on a number of hadiths by the Prophet Muhammad), do they believe him to be Imam Al-Mahdi or Tayyib by this?